# Notepadd ++ Insert hyphen if more than 5 numbers

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a large list of zip codes. Most of the zip codes are 5 digits but some are 9 digits.

I need to insert a hyphen after the 5th number but only if there are more than 5 numbers.

I can find those with 9 digits with

`(^\d{9})`

but I am unsure on how to replace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) and [substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions) we can achieve this.

Find what: `(\d{5})(\d{4})`
Replace with: `$1-$2`

This finds 5 digits followed by 4 digits and creates two capturing groups (one chunk with the first 5 digits and another chunk with the following 4). The '$'-sign followed by a number is a substitution. Here we are saying: Paste the first capturing group, insert a hyphen and paste the second capturing group.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/KnzTus/1